# Implementation check for Kruskal's algorithm used for maze generation

Tags: shortest-path, maze

I have a pathfinding project and I want to use Kruskal's algorithm as a maze generator. I am using a rank-based disjoint set data structure to detect cycles, which seems to be the standard way.

However, the mazes that I generate cannot be solved. Which leads me to think that there might be something wrong with my implementation logic.

```
init_walls() //m by n grid of walls
MST = {}

add each node to MST

while MST is not empty
    node = random_node()
    neighborNode = random_neighbor(node) //up, down, left or right

    if find(node) not equal to find(neighborNode)
        convertWallToPassage(neighborNode)
        union(node, neighborNode)

    delete node from MST
```

`find` and `union` are standard operations in the disjoint set used to detect cycles. If two nodes have the same parent, then they are in the same set and hence forms a cycle. I wonder if there is a gap in my logic, or is my approach flawed?

Answer (score 1):

Kruskal's algorithm iterates through edges, not through vertices. I think it would be better if it looked like:

```
init_walls() //m by n grid of walls

W = set of all walls
p = 0 //counting the number of passages created

While p < m × n - 1
      (u, v) = random_wall()

      if find(u) ≠ find(v)
           convertWallToPassage(u, v)
           union(u, v)
           p = p + 1

      delete (u, v) from walls
```

Here, $m\times n$ represents the number of nodes in an $m$ by $n$ grid. You could use the halting condition `W is empty`, but it is well known that a connected acyclic graph has one more node than edges.

Comment: by set of all walls, do you sets of adjacent nodes? all my grid information are stored as nodes info, not wall info.

Comment: Walls are all pairs of adjacent nodes, indeed. You should use a data structure that permits an iteration over walls (you could create a list of all walls and shuffle it).